# is there any methods to narrowing T?

Tags: typescript

i want when a is string, b will be number[]。
when a is string[], b will be number
is there any solution?
my code is bellow

```js
type g<T> = T extends string ? number[] : number;
function test<T>(a: T, b: g<T>): void {
    if (typeof a === 'string') {
        // i hope T can be narrowing to string , but type of b is still number[] | number
       // and i want when a is string, b will be number[]
        console.log(b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912) of the current TypeScript version. It cannot narrow the type of [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) depending on an unspecified generic type parameter.